# Spring data elasticsearch 6.8.5 how config HTTP port

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I use Elasticsearch version 6.8.5 with 9201 is HTTP port and 9301 is port of cluster node.
On my project, I use spring boot (spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch). On *application.properties* file, I set port of cluster node:

`spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=localhost:9301`

But I don't know how to set HTTP port. So when I start my project, I get an error:

```
NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{de81Kcj-QUqTRdA9HskFWg}{localhost}{localhost:9301}]];
```

I tried to use High Level REST Client setting (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients.rest), but it still not work:

```
@Configuration
public class ElasticsearchConfig {
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public RestHighLevelClient restClient1() {
        final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9201));
        RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(builder);
        return client;
    }
}
```

How can I config HTTP port (not default port)?

Comment: which version of Spring Data Elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: I use 3.2.3 version and my spring boot version is 2.2.2

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following code:

```
@Bean
public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {

    final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()
        .connectedTo("localhost:9201")
        // if you need basic authentication:
        .withBasicAuth("user", "password")
        .build();

    return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
}
```

**Edit:**

Check the complete configuration [from the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#elasticsearch.operations.resttemplate), when using a custom configuration like this, I'd recommend to *not* let Spring Boot try to configure Spring Data Elasticsearch. You can do this by changing the annotation on your application class to

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration.class)
```

Comment: did you name your method `elasticsearchClient()`? The method name will be the name of the bean and that should be _ elasticsearchClient_.

Comment: No, I copy your source code, I only remove `.withBasicAuth("user", "password")` property

Comment: To create _elasticsearchClient_ bean, in *application.properties*, I added configuration:
```spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true```

Comment: thanks for your support, this is my mistake, the cluster node port still 9300 not 9301 :(